# How does python perform bitwise operations to store three values ​in an int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, bit, bitwise-operators

For example, if I have an int with a length of 32 bits, how do I store value A in the first 16 bits, then store value B in bits 17-24, and value C in bits 25-32? And how can I get these three values ​​out of an int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your values *fit* in the assigned bit counts, it's just a question of shifting them to make an `int`, and then unshifting and masking to get them back:

```py
A = 34945
B = 49
C = 233
B_shift = 16
C_shift = 24

result = A + (B << B_shift) + (C << C_shift)
print(result)

resA = result & ((1 << B_shift) - 1)
resB = (result >> B_shift) & ((1 << (C_shift - B_shift)) - 1)
resC = result >> C_shift

print(resA, resB, resC)
```